# Check if file exists using StreamReader

Tags: c++, file, c++-cli, streamreader

I open this file to read data, but if file doesn't exist it throws error. So how can I check if file exists? In console project I can use `ifstream`, where I can check it by writing `if(!file) {}`, and `StreamReader` doesn't allow me to do this.

```
StreamReader^ data = gcnew StreamReader("data.txt");
```

Comment: `File.Exists("data.txt")`

Comment: `File.Exists("data.txt")` may return `true` and it could still throw `FileNotFoundException` when opening it, so you still need to catch exceptions - and if you catch exceptions, checking if the file is there before trying to open it becomes redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_StreamReader__ctor_System_String_).

The exception thrown is `FileNotFoundException` if the file cannot be found.